# In Manipulating the Windows file system I'm getting an exception while moving file from one directory to other

Tags: c#, exception

```
namespace WindowsFileOperation
{
    class WindowsFile
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\kireett\Desktop\mydata");

        DirectoryInfo myDir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\kireett\Desktop\mydata");

        FileInfo[] file = myDir.GetFiles();
        foreach (FileInfo f in file)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("name:{0}, Size:{1} lastAccessTime : {2} lastWriteTime :{3} Directory : {4} extension : {5}",
            f.Name, f.Length, f.LastAccessTime, f.LastWriteTime, f.Directory,f.Extension);
        }
        Directory.Move(@"C:\Users\kireett\Desktop\mydata\1.html", @"C:\Users\kireett\Desktop\Data sheet");
        Console.ReadKey();
       }
    }
}
```

Actually I have that "1.html" file in mydata directory. My aspect is moving that file into another directory "Data sheet". At `Directory.Move` I am getting an exception. Please help me.

Comment: what kind of Exception?

Comment: Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

Comment: That seems like a pretty straightforward exception to me - it can't create a file when the file already exists... So what exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Use **File.Move(...)** instead of **Directory.Move(...)** because you want to move the file not Directory.

2)    You need to move it to another file (rather than a folder), this can also be used to rename.

```
File.Move(@"C:\Users\kireett\Desktop\mydata\1.html", @"C:\Users\kireett\Desktop\Data sheet\2.html");
```

Comment: by using this I'm getting same exception